# cron php job cannot open file on network mounted volume in Mac OS

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that reads a log file that is mounted from another machine on the network. The other machine is a PC and it is mounted via /Volumes/log/ on the Mac. I have validated permissions on the /Volumes/log/ folder and I can read, write etc.

When I run my php job from terminal directly via:

```
php /Users/server/Projects/logreader.php
```

It works perfectly fine. The script opens the /Volumes/log/debug.log file and can read it. However, when I try to run the exact same script via a cron job I get the following error:

Warning: file(/Volumes/log/debug.log): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

Below is the cron job:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/server/Projects/logreader.php > /Users/server/Desktop/output.txt 2&1
```

Below is the lines in the php file to open the log:

```
$path = "/Volumes/log/debug.log";
$data = file("$path", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

I have tried creating the cron job with as the user logged in as as root via sudo su but I get the same error with both.

Output of ls -l on the log file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 server  staff  15179256 14 Jun  2021 /Volumes/log/debug.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissions and owner/group for debug.log? It might be best to check it on the command line with `ls -l /Volumes/log/debug.log`

Comment: It is a warning.  (warning is , in strict sense, different from error)

Comment: I've updated with the ls -l as requested. I know it's a warning but ultimately it doesn't open the file so I can't read it to do anything in the script :) Thanks for the help all - appreciated it

Comment: `/Volumes/log` is probably 700 (`-rwx------`), which means no user other than server can find the file.  You can try changing that to 755 after it mounts.

Comment: Still the same I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 5):

Fixed the issue by giving cron 'Full Disk Access' in System Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Privacy. Thanks All